# How do I best refactor this C# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to refactor the following code, how do I inject notification handler? And minimum original code changes and best refactoring where necessary.

```
public class TestEventHandlers
{
    public TestEventHandlers() { }

    public void OpenMarket(Page page)
    {
        var Id = page.Request["MarketId"];

        var repository = new EntityRepository();
        IEntity market = repository.GetById(Id);

        if (market.State != "Open")
        {
            throw new Exception("The market is not open!");
        }
        else
        {
            market.Open();

            repository.SaveChangesTo(market);

            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.Subject = "market open";
            message.Body = market.ToString() + " was open.";
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("market@mail.com"));

            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
    }

    public void CloseMarket(Page page)
    {
        var Id = page.Request["MarketId"];
        var repository = new EntityRepository();
        IEntity market = repository.GetById(Id);

        if (market.State == "Close")
        {
            throw new Exception("The market is already close!");
        }
        else
        {
            market.Close();

            repository.SaveChangesTo(market);

            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

            var message = new MailMessage();
            message.Subject = "market closed";
            message.Body = market.ToString() + " has been closed.";
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress("market@mail.com"));

            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
    }
}
```

I have already refactored it like below -

```
public class TestEventHandlers
{
        public TestEventHandlers() { }

        public void OpenMarket(Page page)
        {
            var Id = page.Request["MarketId"];
            if (id!=null)
            { 
            var repository = new EntityRepository();
            IEntity market = repository.GetById(Id);

            if (market.State != "Open")
            {
                throw new Exception("The market is not open!");
            }
            else
            {
                market.Open();

                repository.SaveChangesTo(market);

                SendEmailNotification("market open", market.ToString() + " was open.", "market@mail.com");
            }
           }
          else
            {
                throw new Exception("Id can not be null");
            }
        }

        private static void SendEmailNotification(string subject,string body,string emailAddress)
        {
            var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

            var message = new MailMessage();

            message.Subject = subject;
            message.Body = body;
            message.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailAddress));

            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }

        public void CloseMarket(Page page)
        {
            var Id = page.Request["MarketId"];
            if(id!=null)
            {
            var repository = new EntityRepository();
            IEntity market = repository.GetById(Id);

            if (market.State == "Close")
            {
                throw new Exception("The market is already close!");
            }
            else
            {
                market.Close();

                repository.SaveChangesTo(market);

                SendEmailNotification("market closed", market.ToString() + " has been closed.", "market@mail.com");
            }
        }
           else
            {
                throw new Exception("Id can not be null");
            }
       }
    }
```

Comment: you may want to merge `CloseMarket` and `OpenMarket`. you only change its state to Close or Open. a parameter would reduce 2 methods to 1.

Comment: I would go with the Badipamagi's suggestion. Also please start adding null checks too. The same new parameter can be used in SendNotification also. And if you're not using send notifications anywhere else you can merge it but from testing point and for keeping separation of concern you can leave as is.

Comment: added null check too but its not good idea to make it as a one method because it makes a huge refactoring to other classes and methods which are using two methods now i.e `OpenMarket(Page page)
 and CloseMarket(Page page)`

Comment: If you want reduce impact on consumers of your class, refactoring the contents of Open/CloseMarket() to a private helper method might be a good option.

Comment: How about optional parameter to newly created function after merging? This way consumer impact is minimum and you can avoid hard coding also.

Comment: thanks can any one show me an example of injection of notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with something like this:

```
public interface INotifier
{
    void SendEmailNotification(string subject, string body, string emailAddress);
}

public class Notifier : INotifier
{
    public void SendEmailNotification(string subject,string body,string emailAddress)
    {
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

        var message = new MailMessage();

        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = body;
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailAddress));

        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }
}

public class TestEventHandlers
{       
    public INotifier Notifier { get; set; }

    public TestEventHandlers()
    {           
        Notifier = new Notifier();
    }

    public void OpenMarket(Page page)
    {
        var Id = page.Request["MarketId"];
        if (id!=null)
        { 
            var repository = new EntityRepository();
            IEntity market = repository.GetById(Id);

            if (market.State != "Open")
            {
                throw new Exception("The market is not open!");
            }
            else
            {
                market.Open();

                repository.SaveChangesTo(market);

                Notifier.SendEmailNotification("market open", market.ToString() + " was open.", "market@mail.com");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("entityId can not be null");
        }           
    }

    public void CloseMarket(Page page)
    {
        var Id = page.Request["MarketId"];
        if(id!=null)
        {
            var repository = new EntityRepository();
            IEntity market = repository.GetById(Id);

            if (market.State == "Close")
            {
                throw new Exception("The market is already close!");
            }
            else
            {
                market.Close();
                repository.SaveChangesTo(market);
                Notifier.SendEmailNotification("market closed", market.ToString() + " has been closed.", "market@mail.com");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("entityId can not be null");
        }
    }       
}
```

In this your `INotifier` is defaulted to your usual implementation by the constructor, but able to be overridden when required using the accessors. If you'd prefer to always inject in your dependencies even when not testing, you can just add arguments to the constructor.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Fair point @khaled4vokalz - honestly, your copy was just more concise than OPs. I didn't want to have two copies of the Open/CloseMarket methods, when they're _exactly_ the same code. I'll edit to remove your changes immediately.

Comment: Nah, you were right - rude dick move on my part. My apologies.

Comment: hmm what is        ` RepositoryProvider = new EntityRepositoryProvider();`
where this comes from `EntityRepositoryProvider` ? do you mean to use `IEntityRepositoryProvider`? i'm confused

Comment: I think you mean to say `RepositoryProvider = new IEntityRepositoryProvider();` and use it like ` var repository = RepositoryProvider.Get();`  is it so?

Comment: I'm assuming that your `IEntityRepository` is probably `IDisposable`, so you'd want to close it off when you're done with it right? If that's the case you'd want to move construction of your Repository out to a factory class of some sort that you can inject in. I'll update the answer to include an implementation.

Comment: currently I'm also not sure about this code
`  var repository = new EntityRepository();
                    IEntity market = repository.GetById(Id);`
so we do not inject this. we will inject only notification code for now, please help me to do notification inject only and leave other code as it is- thanks

Comment: Solution updated @Neo - there's an implementation of `IEntityRepositoryProvider` in there now as `EntityRepositoryProvider`. It's pretty simple as you can see.

Comment: If that's the case @Neo, then you can just leave out the IEntityRepositoryProvider stuff. You're missing out on the opportunity to stub your repository for test purposes though. Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this @Neo

```
public class TestEventHandlers
{
    public void OpenMarket(Page page)
    {
        ChangeMarketState(page, "Open", "market@mail.com");
    }

    public void CloseMarket(Page page)
    {
        ChangeMarketState(page, "Close", "market@mail.com");
    }

    private static void SendEmailNotification(string subject,string body,string emailAddress)
    {
        var smtpClient = new SmtpClient();

        var message = new MailMessage();

        message.Subject = subject;
        message.Body = body;
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress(emailAddress));

        smtpClient.Send(message);
    }

    public void ChangeMarketState(Page page, string changeStateTo, string sendMailTo)
    {
        var Id = page.Request["MarketId"];
        if(Id != null)
        {
            var repository = new EntityRepository();
            IEntity market = repository.GetById(Id);

            if (market.state == changeStateTo)
            {
                if(changeStateTo == "Close")
                    throw new Exception("The market is already close!");
                else
                    throw new Exception("The market is not open!");
            }
            else
            {
                string currentMarketState = string.empty;
                string mailHeader = string.empty;
                if(changeStateTo == "Close")
                {
                   market.Close();
                   currentMarketState = market.ToString() + " has been closed.";
                   mailHeader = "market closed";
                }
                else
                {
                   market.Open();
                   currentMarketState = market.ToString() + " was open.";
                   mailHeader = "market open";
                }

                repository.SaveChangesTo(market);

                SendEmailNotification(mailHeader, currentMarketState, sendMailTo);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("entityId can not be null");  
        }
    }
}
```